# Java FOR loop incrementing and passing new variable to method

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to pass variables to a function, have it loop through a for loop and pass the new variable to an existing function. For example my original class looks like this

```
class Calculations {

//declare the variables in the class
double TotalPay;
double Sales;
double Salary;
double Commission;
double SalesTarget;
double AccelFactor;
double SalesIncentive;
double Increment;
double NewAccelFactor;
double TableSales = Sales * .5;

public Calculations(double Sales, double Salary, double Commission, double SalesTarget, double AccelFactor, double SalesIncentive, double Increment) { //calculations function - can be used when processing multiple inputs as well
    this.Salary = Salary;
    this.Sales = Sales;
    this.Commission = Commission;
    this.AccelFactor = AccelFactor;
    this.SalesTarget = SalesTarget;
    this.SalesIncentive = SalesIncentive;
    this.Increment = Increment;

}

public void calculatePay() { //calculate the total pay using the above variables that have been set

    if (Sales < SalesIncentive) {
        TotalPay = Salary + (Sales * Commission);
    }
    if (Sales == SalesIncentive || (Sales > SalesIncentive && Sales < SalesTarget * 2)) {
        TotalPay = Salary + ((Sales * Commission) * AccelFactor);
    }
    if (Sales > SalesTarget * 2) {
        TotalPay = Salary + ((Sales * Commission) * (AccelFactor * 2));
    }
    if (Sales > SalesTarget * 3) {
        TotalPay = Salary + ((Sales * Commission) * (AccelFactor * 3));
    }
    if (Sales > SalesTarget * 4) {
        TotalPay = Salary + ((Sales * Commission) * (AccelFactor * 4));
    }
    if (Sales > SalesTarget * 5) {
        TotalPay = Salary + ((Sales * Commission) * (AccelFactor * 5));
    }
    if (Sales > SalesTarget * 6) {
        TotalPay = Salary + ((Sales * Commission) * (AccelFactor * 6));
    }
    if (Sales > SalesTarget * 7) {
        TotalPay = Salary + ((Sales * Commission) * (AccelFactor * 7));
    }
    if (Sales > SalesTarget * 8) {
        TotalPay = Salary + ((Sales * Commission) * (AccelFactor * 8));
    }
    if (Sales > SalesTarget * 9) {
        TotalPay = Salary + ((Sales * Commission) * (AccelFactor * 9));
    }
    if (Sales > SalesTarget * 10) {
        TotalPay = Salary + ((Sales * Commission) * (AccelFactor * 10));
    }
}

public double getTotalPay() {
    return TotalPay; //return total pay to use in the output
}
```

}

My new function looks like this

```
    class TableOutput { //trying to output the table, but it's not working so well

//declare the variables in the class
double TotalPay;
double Sales;
double Salary;
double Commission;
double SalesTarget;
double AccelFactor;
double SalesIncentive;
double Increment;
double NewAccelFactor;
double TableSales;
double newSales;
double totalSales;
//int j = 0;

public TableOutput(double Sales, double Salary, double Commission, double SalesTarget, double AccelFactor, double SalesIncentive, double Increment) {
    //assign instances of the variables
    this.Salary = Salary;
    this.Sales = Sales;
    this.Commission = Commission;
    this.AccelFactor = AccelFactor;
    this.SalesIncentive = SalesIncentive;
    this.Increment = Increment;
    this.SalesTarget = SalesTarget;
    this.TableSales = Sales * 0.5;
    this.totalSales = TableSales + Sales;
    this.newSales = newSales;

}

public void createTable() {

    Calculations calc2; //create a new calculations instance
    if (Sales < totalSales) {  //while the sales are less than the TableSales then do this         
        for (double i = Sales; i < totalSales; i += 20000) {  //for the Sales that are less than the TableSales, up the Sales by 20k and keep going until it reaches the limit of Sales *.5
            newSales = i;
            System.out.println("Total Sales             Total Compensation\n");
            calc2 = new Calculations(newSales, Salary, Commission, SalesTarget, AccelFactor, SalesIncentive, Increment);
            calc2.calculatePay();
            for (double j=Sales; j < totalSales; j += 20000) { //keep adding 20k to Sales and send it back to get a running total
                System.out.println(newSales + "            " + calc2.getTotalPay());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is add 20k to the sales and have it increment by 20k while passing that new sales amount back to the calculatePay function. What am I missing here? Shouldn't this be doing exactly that?

```
     for (double i = newSales; i < TableSales; i =+20000) {
                    Calculations calc2;
                    calc2 = new Calculations(newSales, Salary, Commission, SalesTarget, AccelFactor, SalesIncentive, Increment);
                    calc2.calculatePay();
```

In my main function I am calling on this class for the output in such a manner:

```
TableOutput Table1 = new TableOutput(Sales, Salary, Commission, SalesTarget, AccelFactor, SalesIncentive, Increment);
            Table1.createTable();
```

but still no output.

Comment: The statement ` this.Sales = newSales;`  doesn't look proper. Where are you initialising `newSales`?

Comment: I was setting newSales = to Sales. This was so that it could be incremented without making changes to the original Sales variable. Even with changing it to Sales I am still running into the same problem.

Comment: I still don't see it. In the constructor you are assigning `Sales` to `newSales` and effectively initialising both to 0. Can you print the value of `Sales` and `newSales` before the loop and see what values they hold?

Comment: Interesting. I modified my code some and get 20k for newSales and Sales is equal to whatever I put in.

Comment: After going to all the trouble to define `i` and make sure it's incremented, don't you actually want to do anything with it?

Answer (score 3):

There are actually quite a few problems with your code.

**1)** You set `TableSales = Sales * .5;` on initialization. You don't initialize `Sales` to anything so it will default to 0. Thus, `TableSales = 0 *.5;` which means `TableSales` is always 0, which means your while loop `while (Sales < TableSales)` will always be false.

Rather than setting `TableSales` when you first declare it, you could set it in your constructor, like this.

```
public TableOutput(double Sales, double Salary, double Commission, double SalesTarget, double AccelFactor, double SalesIncentive, double Increment) {
    this.Salary = Salary;
    this.Sales = Sales; //corrected this line as well (although you pass the variable newSales in to your constructor, you named the variable Sales in your constructor)
    this.Commission = Commission;
    this.AccelFactor = AccelFactor;
    this.SalesIncentive = SalesIncentive;
    this.Increment = Increment;
    this.SalesTarget = SalesTarget;
    this.TableSales = Sales * 0.5;
}
```

**2)** Your `for` loop is all kinds of messed up.

For one, you are incrementing it improperly. You say `i = +20000;` which is merely saying i = 20000 on every iteration of your loop. You want `i += 20000`, which will add 20000 to `i` on every iteration.

Also, you are never using `i` in your `for` loop anyway. I believe what you are trying to do is increment the `newSales` value by 20000 every time through the loop, but what your code does currently is passes in 0 to the `Calculations` constructor every time, because you always pass in the `newSales` variable, which is always 0 since you never assign a value to it.

I believe what you are trying to accomplish would look more like this.

```
for (double sales = 0; sales < TableSales; sales += 20000) {
    Calculations calc2;
    calc2 = new Calculations(sales, Salary, Commission, SalesTarget, AccelFactor, SalesIncentive, Increment);
    calc2.calculatePay();
    System.out.println(calc2.getTotalPay());
}
```

**EDIT after OP's code update:**

Your `while (Sales < TableSales)` loop will still never run.

This is because of two things:

First, is because you are passing in 0 for `Sales` when you call the constructor of your `TableOutput` class, so `TableSales` and `Sales` will both be 0. You would need to start sales out at a non-zero number.

Second, you need to re-think your logic here anyway. When you create a `TableOutput` instance, you are setting `TableSales` to half of whatever `Sales` is. So:

```
If Sales = 10000, then TableSales = 5000
If Sales = 30000, then TableSales = 15000
...
```

So `Sales` will always be greater than `TableSales` so your while loop will never run.

Comment: What class is your main function in? And where are you setting the values that you are passing in to your `TableOutput` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

**One of the problem I see is**

Each time in iteration you are creating new object *Calculations calc2*

You need to do the following:

```
Calculations calc2;//Place this here
for (double i = newSales; i < TableSales; i =+20000) {
    calc2 = new Calculations(newSales, Salary, Commission, SalesTarget, AccelFactor, SalesIncentive, Increment);
    calc2.calculatePay();
    }
```

**Next problem**

> i =+20000//incorrect// This is equal to i = 20000
>
> i +=20000//correct// This is equal to i = i + 20000

Comment: That seemed to work for the iteration, but I am still not getting any output from the entire class.

Comment: @kerinr What do you get? Error? Unexpected output?

Comment: No output from this function at all.

Comment: Looks like __while (Sales < TableSales)__ is always false. Are you sure, Sales is less than TableSales?

Comment: Correct. I said that newSales= Sales and TableSales = Sales*.5. This should have made it so that Sales could catch up to TableSales correct? eventually making it false and kicking it out?

Comment: @kerinr See the Edit on my answer